# Registration Form - Checkbox Is Inserted on new rows in Database

Tags: php, database, insert, row

I'm Practising PHP programming. I have made a Registration Form which has

2 Text Area (For First Name and Last)
2 Radio Buttons (For Gender Selection - Haven't started work on that yet)
8 Check boxes (4 each for Subject and Hobbies)

I have a Database Table by the name of persons which has

5 Columns (FirstName,LastName,Gender,Subject,Hobbies)

The Data from the form is being fetched, but each check box is inserted in the next row below the name.

For example David Bekham  the subject php asp and hobby tv reading instead of appearing on the same row and against the name of the record, they appear on the next row.

As this is my first time, my question is

Q1 :- Is that how a record for such a form supposed to appear?
Q2 :- If not then where/what is the problem?
Q3 :- Could you either help me radio button code or provide me an easy link to learn it.

**HTML FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

<title>Insert Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Insert to Register </h1>


<form name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php" >
<fieldset>
<legend> Registration Form </legend> 

FirstName <input type="text" name="a" value="Enter firstname"/>
<br/><br/>
LastName <input type="text" name="b" value="Enter lastname"/>
<br/><br/>



<h3> Gender selection </h3>
Male <input type="radio" name="gender"/> female <input type="radio" name="gender"/>
<br/><br/>


<h3> Subject selection </h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" value="php"/> PHP 
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" value="asp"/> ASP.NET 
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" value="html"/> HTML 
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" value="css"/> CSS 
<br/><br/>


<h3> Hobbies selection </h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="hb[]" value="tv"/> Tv 
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="hb[]" value="pc"/> Computer  
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="hb[]" value="book"/> Reading books 
<br/>
<input type="checkbox"  name="hb[]" value="games"/> Games 
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</fieldset>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**php file**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

<title>Processing_Insert_main</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

// =============== code for Connection_SQLi ==============================      

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Ismat_db");
//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Cannot connect to mysqli:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// =============== code for Submit_input type ================================

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

// ========== code for Name_TextArea ===============        

$sqlta = "INSERT INTO persons(FirstName,LastName)VALUES ('$_POST[a]','$_POST[b]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sqlta))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "record added for name<br/>";


  // ====== code for subject_checkbox ================  
$s = $_POST['sb'];
$how_many=count($s);

for($i=0;$i<$how_many;$i++)
{
    echo "You Selected: " .$s[$i]."<br/>";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO persons(Subject) VALUES('$s[$i]')"))
    {
        echo "Not Recorded".mysqli_error($con);
    }
    echo "Record Added for subject<br/>";
}

   // ============ Code for Hobbies_checkbox ========================   
$h = $_POST['hb'];
$how_many=count($h);

for($i=0;$i<$how_many;$i++)
{
    echo "You Selected: " .$h[$i]."<br/>";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO persons(Hobbies) VALUES('$h[$i]')"))
    {
        echo "Not Recorded".mysqli_error($con);
    }
    echo "Record Added for Hobby<br/>";
}

     //============================================================

   echo '<br/>'.'<a href="insert_main.html">'. "Back" . '</a>'; 

   }

   ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Are you having a problem with something? I don't seem to quite understand what your question is. Is your form working and data is in fact, inserted into your database? Or is this just a question of `how it's placed` in your database?

Comment: Hi @Fred my code is working fine,everything being selected is going into the database BUT the values from the check box(s) appear to be on the next row below the name in the table, so if I selected 4 check boxes I would get 5 rows, one for the name, and four for the check box each. I don't know if this is the right way of how the data should appear or if there is something wrong then what?

Comment: ah ok, I see. Well, from what I saw on SO, I doubt that's a good way of doing it, and I for one am not an expert in that field. I would first Google your question and you might end up finding a link to an (answered) question here on SO. I'll go over your code to see if I can come up with something, but don't hold me to it, cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I am also trying to google out the answer. The problem is just with how the data should be placed in the table in one row. :(

Comment: You're welcome. Well my friend, from what I could tell by your code, I couldn't come up with a viable answer for you, *sorry*. Keep looking, I'm sure you'll find something, cheers.

Comment: No Problem @Fred - I'm sure you wanted to help and that meant a lot - Thank you once again for giving me your precious time :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How is your table structured? I would need to see the structure to be able to give you an actual query but it looks to me like you are inserting each value into the database as part of a separate query (which will always result in separate rows being inserted in the database). If you are storing the persons firstname, lastname, hobbies, and sports, etc in one row of your table you would need to do your query and insert values in 1 query not separate queries. So if you are currently doing:

```
"INSERT INTO persons(FistName, LastName)VALUES ('$_POST[a]','$_POST[b]')";
"INSERT INTO persons(Subject) VALUES('$s[$i]')"
"INSERT INTO persons(Hobbies) VALUES('$h[$i]')"
```

you should rather do:

```
"INSERT INTO persons(FistName, LastName, Subject, Hobbies) VALUES('$_POST[a]','$_POST[b]','$s[$i]','$h[$i]')"
```

Also for correct HTML standards compliance, readability, and accessibility for people with text readers etc. you should insert the text for each input as a label. So what I mean is instead of:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" value="php"/> PHP 
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" value="asp"/> ASP.NET
```

you should use:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" id="checkbox_php" value="php"/><label for="checkbox_php">PHP</label> 
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" id="checkbox_asp" value="asp"/><label for="checkbox_asp">ASP.NET</label>
```

Then you can use CSS to arrange the labels and checkboxes as you wish (float, etc). For checkboxes to appear correctly and vertically aligned with their labels I normally use tables. This is not ideal (as it's not the intended use of tables) but it gets around cross browser issues (and older browser issues) of the vertical alignment of these items in some browsers as well as keeps the label on the same line as the checkbox itself. For example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="sb[]" id="checkbox_php" value="php"/></td>
<td><label for="checkbox_php">PHP</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

On a side note your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. You should read up about [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (if you use the MySQLi extensions).

Comment: Thanks for this Zappa, can you please tell me how the information is placed in one row of the table in accordance to my form? I am getting each checkbox value on a new  row in my table :(

Comment: @AbbasAnsari This is not an actual answer to your question. Your present HTML has no bearing on the issue at hand.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot Fred for the -1 Fred. The question wasn't very clear as your comment posted above mentions...

Comment: @Fred Yup, true ... my problem is how the data is to be placed in database ~ Programming is so tough :(

Comment: @Zappa You should've read the question and read my comments/question to the OP. That's how I found out what the actual problem was.

Comment: @AbbasAnsari you need to do the insert into the database in a single query if you want it to be in the same row. Doing individual inserts will create separate rows in the database.

Comment: @Fred ever think that perhaps I was typing my answer at the time you wrote your comment? sigh.

Comment: @Zappa mysqli_query() takes only two parameters, I gave it $con, and the insert query .. how do i give multiple queries? if there is any syntax that you know please do share

Comment: @Zappa No, I minus -1 you 4-5 minutes after you posted your answer. Consult the timestamp. *The proof is in the pudding*.

Comment: @Fred Its thanks to people like you that I don't bother helping people on here much. The guy is trying to learn coding so a little help with respect to how he does things can only be a good thing

Comment: @Zappa Thanks - and my apology for my bad English and communication skills.

Comment: @AbbasAnsari no problem :) Its not your English that's the problem just that some people here think they own the place lol. Hope I can help you out

Comment: @Zappa - I saw the INSERT Query, would this work with the FOR loops, As for each set of Checkbox I have a for loop that obtains the value for each check box selected. So do I have to just place this query on the top in a variable and call it in the end of the code? (good approach?)

Comment: @AbbasAnsari how I normally do this sort of thing is to use a variable for each value. First declare the variables as blank at the start of your code e.g. $firstname = ''; then loop through and add a value to the variable in the for loop e.g. $firstname = $_POST[a]; Then do one insert after all post variables are looped through and then you can use these variables in your query at the end. If you don't understand I can post another answer :)

Comment: @AbbasAnsari also just realised if you are trying to store more than one hobby for example then you may need to redo how your table is structured. If you only have one field for hobbies for example you could only ever store a string with all hobbies on one line or you would need to create separate rows for each possible option of hobby

Comment: @Zappa - I got what you mean by blank variables, but i didnt get the loop part that easily. You mean to say simply call the value from the check box in the loop body $course_subject= $POST['sb']; or would it be $course_subject=$s[$i]?

Comment: okay so this little task has become so complicated :/ - anyway, when I created the table, I used the basic syntax and it created columns, How can I alter this structure?

Comment: Can we upload images here? I can show a print screen of my table

Comment: Sorry my mistake as I chose firstname as the example which doesn't need the loop. If you only want to allow 1 subject value per database column then you would need to join each value of subject in the for loop (e.g. $course_subject .= ', '.$s[$i];) If you only want one value of subject per database column then you would need multiple variables (e.g. $course_subject1 = ', '.$s[$i]; $course_subject2 = ', '.$s[$i];). Hope this makes sense lol.

Comment: Okay, So this is what I understood

If I wish to place the value of one subject in per column against a row then I shall have to use $course_subject= ','.$s[$i]; //This will only place php in the column of subject against the first row.

If I wish to place php,asp,html,css all under the subject column against the same row of the name of one person I shall have to use 
$course_subject1 = ', '.$s[$i]; $course_subject2 = ', '.$s[$i];

correct me please If I understood wrong.

Comment: You almost got it :) I will post some code in a minute which will hopefully explain what I mean.

Comment: @Zappa here's what I did - I put in this line in the for loop 

for($i=0;$i<$how_many;$i++)
 {
  echo "You Selected: " .$s[$i]."<br/>";
  **$course_subject = $s[$i];**
         }

And in the end This line for insertion

**$sqlta = "INSERT INTO persons(FirstName, LastName, Subject, Hobbies) VALUES('$_POST[a]','$_POST[b]','$course_subject','$life_hobby')";**

The code goes in perfect, and displays one subject under the Subject column in the table. IF I select two check-boxes it then displays the last checked. Is there a way to display all four subjects in the  column with a comma?

Comment: Sorry having problems with codepad as I was going to paste some code to explain it better. If you select 2 checkboxes you can insert both values separated by commas if you change your code to: $course_subject .= ', '. $s[$i]; Notice the dot ".=" as this means concatenate :)

Comment: @Zappa Wow - IT WORKED!!!! 
The only thing that I need to figure out now is the comma that comes in the start. BUT THANKS ALOT!!!!! :D :D :D ... all four values are under the same column

Comment: @Zappa YOu really did help alot, Is there anyway on this website that I could return to you the favour, like "VOTE" or "STAR" or "COMPLIMENT" on profile or here?

Comment: Awesome :) what you need to do to avoid the comma first is to put an if statement like: if ($i >0){$course_subject .= ', '. $s[$i];} else{$course_subject = $s[$i];}. Glad I could help.

Comment: Done! And THANKS a MILLION for all the help either with HTML standards and DATABASE I got to learn a lot.

Comment: You are more than welcome. The standards thing is just so you learn the right way. Don't want you learning the wrong way as it will become a habit :) Using labels also has the added advantage that if you click the labels name it also checks the checkbox so makes sense to use it. Don't forget to escape the variables you are putting into the database too to avoid injections. Good luck with your learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$chkhobby=implode(',',$_POST['chkhobby']);
<tr>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <td>
                            Male<input type="radio" name="gender" checked="checked" value="1">
                            Female<input type="radio" name="gender" checked="checked" value="0">

                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Hobbies</th>
                        <td>
                            read<input id="check_1" type="checkbox" name="chkhobby[]" value="read">
                            write<input id="check_2" type="checkbox" name="chkhobby[]" value="write">
                            play<input id="check_4" type="checkbox" name="chkhobby[]" value="play"> 
                        </td>
                </tr>
```